# Get contacts that are moving through the Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

What is the best way to see contacts that are still engaged in a specific Journey (have not left).
There are no "contact update" related activities that would make it easy to define who left already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the said Contact Update activity as the last activity before exiting the journey and update the journey's Data Extension. So you would have to:

1. Add an additional field to the journey data extension, for example, "Stage"

[image]

2. Add the Contact Update activity at the end of the journey and set it to update the "Stage" column with a value "finished"

[image]

You could actually add a Contact Update activity at every stage of your journey, to mark each activity that the subscriber was engaged in, for example, "Email 1 sent", "Wait for 1 Day", etc.